# How to check if the first letter in is uppercase in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm validating the first name in javascript. I have to check if the first letter is uppercase. below is what I've tried but non of them worked.

```
//if(inputtext.match(upperCase))
//if(inputtext(0).value === inputtext(0).value.toUpperCase())
//if(inputtext.charAt(0) === inputtext.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
//if(upperCase.test(inputtext))
```

this is my code:

```
var inputtext = document.getElementById('fName');
var upperCase = /^[A-Z]/;
if(inputtext.charAt(0) === inputtext.charAt(0).toUpperCase()){
     return true;
}
else{
     console.log(inputtext.value + " : first letter is not uppercase.");
        return false;
}
```

I expect to get a message from the console tells that the first letter is not uppercase.

Comment: `return` is for functions. You're not declaring a function anywhere. When is your code being executed? Did you maybe miss to use `inputtext.addEventListener('change' function() {if(inputtext.charAt(0) === inputtext.charAt(0).toUpperCase()){
     return true;
}
else{
     console.log(inputtext.value + " : first letter is not uppercase.");
        return false;
}})`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do:

```js
const isFirstLetterCapital = (word) => word && word.length !== 0 ? word[0] === word[0].toUpperCase() : false;

var word = "Hello world";
console.log(isFirstLetterCapital(word)); // true

var second = "hello world"
console.log(isFirstLetterCapital(second)); // false

var emptyString = ""
console.log(isFirstLetterCapital(emptyString)); // false


var nullString = null
console.log(isFirstLetterCapital(nullString)); // false
```

Comment: please try `third = ""; console.log(third[0] === third[0].toUpperCase()); `

Comment: **return ERROR for empty string !**

Comment: @MisterJojo Of course it will, since there's no first letter to test. You need to check that beforehand.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms  Of course it will not, Did you really chek it before ?.

Comment: ayt updated the comment to address @MisterJojo 's issue

Comment: @IamL have the courage to put your code in a snippet. it hides the error, but it does not give true or false in this case

Comment: but you would be better advised to use: `const isFirstLetterCapital = word => ( typeof(word)==='string' && word.length>0) ? word.charAt(0) === word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() : false;` since you started to test the NULL value, and forget to test other types, array, numbers ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Convert the first character to uppercase and compare

```js
var inputtext = document.getElementById('fName');

function isFirstCharCapital(){
if(inputtext.value!="")
  console.log(inputtext.value[0] === inputtext.value[0].toUpperCase())
  else
  console.log("Enter something")
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" onchange="isFirstCharCapital()">
```

Answer (score 0):

what about making a wrapper ?

```js
String.prototype.isFirstCharUpperCase = function(){
  return (this.length<1) ? false : this.charAt(0)===this.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
}

console.log('Hello     =>', 'Hello'.isFirstCharUpperCase() )       // true
console.log('world     =>', 'world'.isFirstCharUpperCase() )      // false
console.log('Élements  =>', 'Élements'.isFirstCharUpperCase() )  // true
console.log('(empty)   =>', ''.isFirstCharUpperCase() )         // false
```

`if (this.length <1) return false`  every one here forget this part ;)

or simply: (using a regex is not a good idea if you have to test capital letters with a diacritic sign)

```js
String.prototype.isFirstCharCapital = function()
{
  return /^[A-Z]/.test(this)
}

console.log('Hello     =>', 'Hello'.isFirstCharCapital() )       // true
console.log('world     =>', 'world'.isFirstCharCapital() )      // false
console.log('Élements  =>', 'Élements'.isFirstCharCapital() )  // false !
console.log('(empty)   =>', ''.isFirstCharCapital() )         // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstNameField = document.getElementById('fName');
const firstName = firstNameField.value;

function isFirstLetterCapital(firstName){
  if(firstName && firstName.length > 0 ) {
   return firstName.charAt(0) === firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }
  else {
   console.error("firstName must have a value"); 
  }
}
```